# How post Increment ++ Operator works while initialization

Tags: java, arrays, operators, post-increment, unary-operator

I have written following code to reverse the given String:

```
String str = "abcdef";
char[] strToChar = str.toCharArray();
char[] outString = new char[strToChar.length];

for(int j = 0; j < strToChar.length; ) {
    int len = strToChar.length-j;
    outString[j++] = strToChar[strToChar.length-j];
}
```

As per my understanding initialization happens from *Right* to *Left*. Hence, `strToChar[strToChar.length-j]` here should throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`.

But it runs fine. How is that happening? Shouldn't it evaluate to this?

```
outString[0] = strToChar[6];    //This should throw exception
```

Comment: well, you assign `outString[0] = strToChar[6-1]` here, which will result in no error. The key here is the `j++` which will lead to the right part not throwing an exception, as the left hand assignment variable will increase the `j` value due to the postincrement

Comment: The [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7) states: "The Java programming language guarantees that the operands of operators appear to be evaluated in a specific evaluation order, namely, from _left to right_."

Answer (score 1):

If I look at your code, then you have written your condition to be

```
for(int j = 0; j < strToChar.length;)
```

here **strToChar.length** will return you the actual length of the array which is 6.

The correct way to iterate an array with for loop would be:

```
for(int j = 0; j < strToChar.length;j++)
```

The index starting from 0 and going to < strToChar.length

Comment: well the missing last part of the for loop is the major part why there is no exception. So with the current implementation he´d either have to change it to `strToChar[strToChar.length-j-1]` or he´d be running into the exception he was curious about not beeing raised.

Comment: @SomeJavaGuy That's true!

Comment: "The correct way to iterate an array with for loop [...]" no, this way is not "the correct way", it is the most common way. OP's code is somewhat uncommon but works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Acording to the java [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7):

> The Java programming language guarantees that the operands of
>   operators appear to be evaluated in a specific evaluation order,
>   namely, from left to right.

Which means `j` is incremented before evaluating the right side of the expression.

So accordingly this code:

```
outString[j++] = strToChar[strToChar.length-j];
```

is evaluated to:

```
outString[0] = strToChar[6-1];
```

instead of:

```
outString[0] = strToChar[6-0];
```