# Increment operator works different while running and debugging

Tags: java, debugging, operators, inspect, pre-increment

Here is the portion of the code which works weird while debugging

```
public static void main(String[] args) { //Line-1
    int a = 5; //Line-2
    System.out.println(++a); //Line-3
} //Line-4
```

When I run it in normal mode it gives output as `6` which is correct. But while debugging I kept a break point at `Line-3` and first time when I inspected the value of `++a` it showed 6 next time it was 7,8,9...

When I ended the program it showed output as 10 in the console. Why is that?

These solutions [C++ - Eclipse behavior is different while debugging and running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52036042/c-eclipse-behavior-is-different-while-debugging-and-running), [How post Increment ++ Operator works while initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43494358/how-post-increment-operator-works-while-initialization) didn't give any proper idea.

Comment: The debugger, when evaluating the expression, is incrementing `a` over and over again on each evaluation. i.e. evaluating `++a` has side effects, and can not be done without affecting application state

Comment: @Michael that's right instead of inspecting `++a` if I inspect just `a` there won't be a change

Answer (score 2):

When you evaluate the value of the expression ++a in debug mode, you really increment the variable. So it impacts the final result.